# How to see the command attached to a bash alias?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

Suppose I have an alias in the bash shell. Is there a simple command to print out what command the alias will run?

Answer (score 725, accepted):

The `type` builtin is useful for this. It will not only tell you about aliases, but also functions, builtins, keywords and external commands.

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ type rm
rm is /bin/rm
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ type psgrep
psgrep is a function
psgrep () 
{ 
    ps -ef | { 
        read -r;
        printf '%s\n' "$REPLY";
        grep --color=auto "$@"
    }
}
```

`type -a cmd` will show all the commands by that name in order of precedence, which is useful for the `ls` alias above, where the alias itself calls `ls`.

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
```

This tells you that when you run `ls`, `/bin/ls` will be used, and `--color=auto` will be included in its list of arguments, in addition to any other you add yourself.

Comment: what to do when an alias contains MORE aliases?

Comment: @user251046 keep using `type` until you hit something other than an alias ...

Comment: I like this answer because `type` will parse/interpret any quotes, so you can make sure the quotes are right.

Comment: I got `ls is aliased to 'ls --color=auto'`, but how can I get one layer deeper, to see whether it uses /bin/ls or /usr/local/bin/ls or what?

Comment: @krubo `type -a ls` will show all ls commands found in order of preference. Whichever is right below the alias is the one that will be executed by the alias.

Comment: `type -a ls` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: cool, I've been using `which` for years, but that fails on aliases and functions (at least on my system, YMMV). Have to remember to use `type` instead...

Answer (score 245):

Just type `alias` while at the Shell prompt.  It should output a list of all currently-active aliases.

Or, you can type `alias [command]` to see what a specific alias is aliased to, as an example, if you wanted to find out what the `ls` alias was aliased to, you could do `alias ls`.

Comment: Or type `alias ls` to find out what specifically `ls` is aliased to.

Comment: @poolie Indeed.  I think the question was to see *all* the aliases, though, which is why i did not elaborate further on the alias command.

Comment: while this works for aliases, it doesn't work if you've defined a custom shell function. `type` however, works in both cases.

Answer (score 76):

I really like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> as I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1416125/259953). It "expands" the currently typed command line, meaning it performs alias expansion (amongst other things).

What does that mean? It turns any alias, that might be currently written on the command line, into what the alias stands for.

For example, if I type:

```
$ ls
```

and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, it is turned into

```
$ ls --time-style=locale --color=auto
```

Comment: have this an equivalent on other distros?

Comment: @sepehr Works on Debian, I assume it's a bash feature and should work on any distribution.

Comment: you're right, it works on bash but I have zsh and it doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: was really helpful. I had a different goal of expanding one of the previous bash commands logged in history with, i.e., !394, so that I could edit it first before executing

Comment: How to accomplish this on bash OSX?

Comment: It has one caveat. When an alias includes necessary quotes, they will be removed. So, I get `squeue -u davidmh -o %.18i %.9P %.25j %.8u %.8T %.10M %.9l %.6D %R ` instead of `squeue -u davidmh -o "%.18i %.9P %.25j %.8u %.8T %.10M %.9l %.6D %R "`

Comment: any Mac equivalent?

Comment: Dove into this rabbit-hole today.  This feature is brought to you by readline.  You can see readline's current key-mappings by typing `bind -P`.  You can modify readline's keymappings by creating/editing its config file `~/.inputrc`.  Get more info with `man readline`.

Answer (score 24):

Strictly speaking correct answer is using BASH_ALIASES array, e.g.:

```
$ echo ${BASH_ALIASES[ls]}
ls -F --color=auto --show-control-chars
```

Comment: I found this useful in a situation where I wanted programmatic access to the actual statement being aliased without the human-useful stuff around it.

Comment: this isn't working in zsh

Comment: @ProGrammar the question was about bash - for zsh you should look questions about zsh

Comment: Bingo. Exactly what I needed, same as @M.Justin - I want to stack more switches onto the current `ls` alias without altering what's there. So I'm going `alias ls="${BASH_ALIASES[ls]} --time-style=iso"` for my case.

Comment: Great for 'watch' command which typically doesn't see aliases: watch $(echo "${BASH_ALIASES[ll]}")

Answer (score 6):

You could use the `which` command.

If you set an alias for `ls` as `ls -al` and then type `which ls`, you will see:

`ls:   aliased to ls -al`.

Comment: bash has no `which` command.

Comment: Not working for me..

Comment: `which` is a bad way to lookup aliases as explained here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10525/how-to-use-which-on-an-aliased-command   It doesn't even work for me for aliases in bash on Ubuntu.

Comment: Only solution that worked for me on MacOS/zsh (This is a Bash question on AskUbuntu I know, but AskUbuntu shows up first in Google)

Answer (score 3):

At terminal

```bsh
$ alias | grep ALIAS
```

Outputs

```bsh
ALIAS='some_command'
```

Replace `ALIAS` with your alias.

Comment: Redundant. Just run `alias <command>`