# Translate alias command to the full form

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm using Ubuntu terminal to manage my works. I created some alias names that help me to do the work faster.

for example:

```
$ alias kprod="kubectl --namespace=hello"
```

Then use it like this:

```
$ kprod get pods
```

One of my major tasks is to find when is my application is ready to run on the cloud, so I call this code:

```
$ kprod get pods | grep APPNAME
```

But I need to run it again and again until it ready. I want to use `watch` command to simplify this task. Unfortunately, watch not working because `kprod` is an alias.

```
$ watch kprod get pods
sh: 1: kprod: not found
```

### My Questions:

1. Is this possible to solve this specific problem with `watch` shell command?
2. Is it possible to make a more generic solution that will "translate" the command for the actual expression? For example:

   ```
   $ kprod get pods | TRANSLATE
   kubectl --namespace=hello get pods
   ```

which make it work with `watch` and any other application?

### UPDATE

Using `type` command is similar but different. As I tried, it's impossible to give it a full expression and "translate" it because it's trying to convert each token of the expression seperatly. Of cause the pod (in my example above) is not alias string...

For example:

```
$ type kprod get pods
kprod is aliased to `kubectl --namespace=hello'
-bash: type: get: not found
-bash: type: pods: not found
```

Yes, i can do it manually with the `type` command, but it's manually. I looking for automated way.

Comment: Related: [How to see the command attached to a bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102093/how-to-see-the-command-attached-to-a-bash-alias)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see the command attached to a bash alias?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102093/how-to-see-the-command-attached-to-a-bash-alias)

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: There are a lot of useful answers on that duplicate, please don't only look at the accepted one.

Comment: Sorry, but I passed over all the examples there (`which`, `type` and `alias`) and none of them get me into the this point.

Comment: @pLumo the question isn't about finding what an alias is doing but about using an alias with `watch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make a little script called `watch_alias` (or whatever) that will expand the alias and then pass the expanded command to `watch`. Save the following as `~/bin/watch_alias` and make it executable (`chmod a+x ~/bin/watch_alias`):

```
#!/bin/bash

## enable alias expansion in scripts
shopt -s expand_aliases
## source the .bashrc file where your aliases should be
. ~/.bashrc

## The first argument of the script is the alias
aliasCom=$1
## Remove the 1st argument from the $@ array (the script's arguments)
shift

## Parse the output of type to get what the real command is
realCom=$(type "$aliasCom" | grep -oP "\`\K.[^']+")
## watch the unaliased command
watch bash -c "$realCom '$@'"
```

You can then run this instead of `watch`:

```
watch_alias kprod get pods
```

Comment: Interesting! the command `watch_alias kprod get pods` working great. I couldn't make it work with pipes. For example: `watch_alias 'kprod get pods | grep HELLO'`

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever no, you can't watch pipes anyway, that isn't a problem with the alias. Try `watch ls | grep a` or something. The `pipe` isn't passed to `watch`, it is trying to pipe the _output_ of `watch`. The way to watch pipes is to give the whole command in a new shell: `watch bash -c 'ls | grep a'`. It should work with my (updated) script if you run it like this: `watch_alias kprod 'get pods | grep HELLO'`

Answer (score 1):

Aliases serve for you as a shortcut in the terminal. It is not the other way around. The way you intend to use aliases is not how they are intended.

In principle, just type out the command in full when used in automation. However, you could turn your aliases into a command by instead creating an executable script:

Contents of a bash script `kprod`

```
#!/bin/bash
kubectl --namespace=hello $@
```

The $@ at the end of the command will expand to all the parameters you passed on the command line.

Put this script in a folder that is in your path. That way, simply typing the name will run the script. Although somewhat more difficult to set up, it is equally easy to use as your alias. In addition, you can also use it in automation.